# localStorage может быть заместо бд?

Tags: javascript

localStorage  может быть заместо **локальной** бд ? Как долго там храниться информация?

Comment: нет, банально потому, что информация хранится на клиенте

Comment: @Etki  Ну так локальной БД)

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых - надо учитывать ограничение на размер - в большинстве современных браузеров для локального хранилища доступно от 5Mb. Для полноценной БД этого может не хватить.

Во-вторых, время хранения официально не регламентируется и оставляется на усмотрение клиентского приложения. В общем случае, время жизни объектов в локальном хранилище недетерминировано, что чревато неприятными последствиями в случае длительного хранения важных данных.
Поэтому, теоретически - возможно, практически - лучше всего хранилище подходить для кэширования/настроек. Многие сайты с JS играми хранят сохранения в локальном хранилище, но если они не бекапятся на сервер - периодически это приводит к неприятным инцидентам.

Существуют некоторые методологии([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326943/when-do-items-in-html5-local-storage-expire/17632458#17632458)), которые позволяют управлять временем жизни объектов в хранилище, но лично я отношу их скорее к хакам, чем к нормальным рабочим решениям.

Полезная статья: [(Англ.)](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-storage/)

Comment: Стоп, так а может лучше тогда использовать Web SQL?

Comment: На первый взгляд более подходяще, но более конкретно по Web SQL сказать не смогу, не имел дела. Насколько я знаю W3C перевели спецификацию WebSQL в разряд рекомендаций не очень давно + FF не поддерживает её вообще.

Comment: Это хорошо) Потому что меня интересует только гуглхром)